# Enum, Unsupported lookup 'eq' for CharField

Tags: python, django

I have piece of code, which worked fine with
Python 3.9 and Django 1.11.

I made an update to Python 3.9 and Django 3.2 and I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Code\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Code\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Code\octo\OctoServ\views.py", line 615, in temp
    sums = qsSchedules.filter(Employee=e).values('Date', 'Type').order_by('Date').annotate(sum=typefilter)
  File "D:\Code\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1091, in annotate
    return self._annotate(args, kwargs, select=True)
  File "D:\Code\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1130, in _annotate
    clone.query.add_annotation(
  File "D:\Code\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1042, in add_annotation
    annotation = annotation.resolve_expression(self, allow_joins=True, reuse=None,
  File "D:\Code\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\aggregates.py", line 48, in resolve_expression
    c.filter = c.filter and c.filter.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
  File "D:\Code\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 104, in resolve_expression
    clause, joins = query._add_q(
  File "D:\Code\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1415, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "D:\Code\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "D:\Code\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1190, in build_lookup
    lhs = self.try_transform(lhs, lookup_name)
  File "D:\Code\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1229, in try_transform
    raise FieldError(
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'eq' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.
```

The error is caused by the line

```
typefilter = Sum('Minutes', filter=(Q(Type__eq=scheduleChoice.G) | Q(Type__eq=scheduleChoice.D)))
```

in views.py, which is as follows

```
[...]
emp = employee.objects.filter(Status=1)
sDate = request.POST["sDate"]
eDate = request.POST["eDate"]

qsSchedules = schedule.objects.filter(Employee__in=emp).filter(Date__gte=sDate).filter(Date__lt=eDate)
typefilter = Sum('Minutes', filter=(Q(Type__eq=scheduleChoice.G) | Q(Type__eq=scheduleChoice.D)))

for e in emp:
    projects = []
    sumSchedules = []
    sums = qsSchedules.filter(Employee=e).values('Date', 'Type').order_by('Date').annotate(sum=typefilter)

[...]
```

The `Type` of `schedule` is an Enum. See models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from enum import Enum

class employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, default=0, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    Status = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class project(models.Model):
    ProjectName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ProjectNumber = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    Status = models.IntegerField()
    ContractAmount = models.FloatField()
    Type = models.IntegerField()

class scheduleChoice(Enum):
    G = "Godziny"
    U = "Urlop"
    Z = "Zwolnienie"
    N = "Nieobecność"
    D = "Delegacja"
    O = "Opieka"

class schedule(models.Model):
    Employee = models.ForeignKey(employee, default=0, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    Project = models.ForeignKey(project, default=0, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    Minutes = models.IntegerField()
    Date = models.DateField()
    Status = models.IntegerField()
    Type = models.CharField(
        max_length = 2,
        choices = [(tag.name, tag.value) for tag in scheduleChoice],
        default = scheduleChoice.G,
    )
```

Do you have any ide what went wrong? When I change `Type__eq=scheduleChoice.G` to `Type=scheduleChoice.G` for all records Sum gives `None`.

Comment: Might the the fact that you are filtering in the `Sum` constructor, which does not support it from what I saw in the declaration of the class.

Comment: I  really don't see support for `__eq` anywhere in the docs, are you sure you're using a valid field lookup prefix?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose I am sure I don't. It was valid in an earlier version of Django, but now it is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scheduleChoice` is an `Enum` and when you write `scheduleChoice.G` it would give you an object like `<scheduleChoice.G: 'Godziny'>` this is not the value that should be stored which is `G`. Even if you call `__str__` of this object it will give `'scheduleChoice.G'` again not matching our expectations.

Since Django 3.0 a few [Enumeration types [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) were added for the choices so you can use them instead:

```
class scheduleChoice(models.TextChoices):
    G = "G", "Godziny"
    U = "U", "Urlop"
    Z = "Z", "Zwolnienie"
    N = "N", "Nieobecność"
    D = "D", "Delegacja"
    O = "O", "Opieka"
```

And in your model field:

```
Type = models.CharField(
        max_length = 2,
        choices = scheduleChoice.choices,
        default = scheduleChoice.G,
    )
```

Next in your query you use some non-existent lookup `eq`, there is no such lookup in Django, instead perhaps you want to use the `exact` lookup (which is also used if you don't specify any lookup):

```
typefilter = Sum('Minutes', filter=(Q(Type=scheduleChoice.G) | Q(Type=scheduleChoice.D)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It is exactly what I was looking for.